# How to preserve query parameter in python list

Tags: python, list

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcases = {}
    params = {}
    tests = {}
    expectations ={}
    append_all_tests = []
    main_input = {}
    testcases["queries"] = ["obama", "london"]
    params["locale"] = "US"
    expectations["type"] = ["president", "city"]

    for i, q in enumerate(testcases['queries']):
        tests["parameters"] = params
        tests["expectations"] = expectations
        tests["query"] = q
        append_all_tests.insert(i, tests)
    main_input["tests"] = append_all_tests
    print main_input
```

My out put is :`{'tests': [{'query': 'london', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}, {'query': 'london', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}]}`

I expect it to be:

```
{'tests': [{'query': 'obama', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}, {'query': 'london', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}]}
```

How do I loop over the number of queries in the list? Please help.

Comment: The main issue stems from the fact that you're overwriting the `query` value of your `tests` dictionary because you reuse it in each of the loops. You can make `tests` initialize a new `dict` in each loop before the assignment to ensure that the final _tests_ are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zwer mentioned this is happening because you are inserting the same object (`tests`) into `append_all_tests` multiple times. You may get rid of this issue by simply creating a new dict object in each iteration:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcases = {}
    params = {}
    expectations ={}

    append_all_tests = []
    main_input = {}

    testcases["queries"] = ["obama", "london"]
    params["locale"] = "US"
    expectations["type"] = ["president", "city"]

    for i, q in enumerate(testcases['queries']):
        tests = {}
        tests["parameters"] = params
        tests["expectations"] = expectations
        tests["query"] = q

        append_all_tests.insert(i, tests)

    main_input["tests"] = append_all_tests
    print main_input
```

Sample output:

```
{'tests': [{'query': 'obama', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}, {'query': 'london', 'expectations': {'type': ['president', 'city']}, 'parameters': {'locale': 'US'}}]}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)